# Can I route DNS entries to the same domain?

Tags: dns, webserver

I have a domain which is showing user data from a php file, and I want to use the url as being the source for which user to display. I have something like example.com and I want that if you type in example.com/peter it should route to http://www.example.com/users/show.php. Also peter.example.com and www.example.com/peter should do the same.

I've tried messing with the DNS settings, but I only made things worse. Can someone please tell me in detail which records I need to create for this to work.

Comment: You will need to just forward the request on that page... So, may be use URL rewriting to accept `www.example.com/user=`, which translates as `www.example.com/name` and then in the code, detect where it should go and forward them. No need to touch DNS

Comment: No need to play with DNS. Handle it in the HTTP part.

Comment: The problem is that I don't get to the php page. My DNS is setup to have an entry for <blank>.example.com web-alias http://www.example.com/users/show.php. And this works when I enter example.com/Peter. However it does not work for www.example.com/Peter neither does it work for peter.example.com. So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing DNS here is www.example.com. Past that, this is all basic URI rewriting.  "web-alias" is just doing URL redirects, but it just happens to be configured in your DNS control panel as a feature, but it's not really doing anything in DNS except resolving to a URI redirector run by your provider (and NOT your webserver).

What's tripping you up is having two DNS names that may be resolving to different web servers.  You didn't supply the real names so I can't check that.  The DNS names `example.com` and `www.example.com` can resolve to different IP addresses, but you probably don't want that if you are running the web server.  You want both to point at your web server then have two Virtual Host definitions, one for each DNS name and add the appropriate URI redirect rules to those definitions.

So if you do that, you don't want this "web-alias" thing at your DNS hosting provider, just A records for both names to direct browsers to your web server.